# Get Ajax POST data on php via Javascript call

Tags: javascript, php, sql-server, knockout.js

First I am conface that I am  **Newbie** to `php`,
I am using jquery(knockout js) at client side & PHP at server side. my code.

**Client side**: I am using `knockout js(Javascript)`. to call my PHP service.

**My Code:**

```
self.VMSaveEditUserMode = function () {
   try {
      var params = { "ClientData": [controllerVM_.ClientID(), controllerVM_.VMList[0].ClientName(), controllerVM_.VMList[0].ShortName(), controllerVM_.VMList[0].Address(), controllerVM_.VMList[0].CreatedBy(), controllerVM_.VMList[0].CityName(), controllerVM_.VMList[0].PostalCode(), controllerVM_.VMList[0].ContactEmail(), controllerVM_.VMList[0].ContactPhone(), controllerVM_.VMList[0].IsCorporate()] };

      $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: URL + "index.php/phpService/SaveClient/" + controllerVM_.TokenKey(),
         data: JSON.stringify(ko.toJS(params)),
         contentType: "application/json",
         async: true,
         dataType: 'json',
         cache: false,
         success: function (response) {
         },
         error: function (ErrorResponse) {
            if (ErrorResponse.statusText == "OK") {
            }
            else {
               alert("ErrorMsg:" + ErrorResponse.statusText);
            }
         }
      });
   }
   catch (error) {
      alert("Catch:" + error);
   }
}
```

**Server Side My Code**, I am using this **PHP** code to connect with **DB**.

**PHP Code**:

```
public function SaveClient($userToken)
    {   
       $value = json_decode($Clientdata);
       echo $value->ClientData[0];
    }
```

**My Question **:

- I am not clear on how to POST data in PHP ? I tried with `$_POST['']` method as well as many more.
- I am using **eclipse** as a **php framework**. so, not able to debug it when i post the data.Normally mode i am able to debug my code.but not from remotely.for that i made changes on `php.ini` file also.

### How to get Response of Post Data on php code ?

### How to debug via remote post ?

**My Request sample:**

**suppose i use**:

**For,  `data: params,`**    only at that time my request format is.

```
ClientData%5B%5D=4&ClientData%5B%5D=kamlesh&ClientData%5B%5D=KAM&ClientData%5B%5D=Junagadh&ClientData%5B%5D=me&ClientData%5B%5D=SANTA+ROSA&ClientData%5B%5D=76220&ClientData%5B%5D=kamlesh.vadiyatar%40gmail.com&ClientData%5B%5D=9998305904&ClientData%5B%5D=false
```

**For,  `data: JSON.stringify(ko.toJS(params)),`**

```
{"ClientData":["4","kamlesh","KAM","Junagadh","me","SANTA ROSA","76220","kamlesh.vadiyatar@gmail.com","9998305904",false]}
```

Comment: try replacing `data: JSON.stringify(ko.toJS(params)),` with `data: params,`

Comment: For debugging this I'd recoment FireBug + FirePHP extensions

Comment: @k102, sorry but i am not familiar with firePHp...and i dont think so, here firebug should help me. as per my knowledge.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand correctly you need to create a PHP service which is able to receive REST-like requests from client.

In order to do thad you need to access *raw POST data*. In PHP its being done like this:

```
$ClientData = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

You can read more about `php://input` in the [wrappers documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php).

Of course from the client's side the data need to be sent using the POST method and as raw  data, i.e. as a string. You can obtain a string from object using `JSON.stringify()` which you already do.

If you pass an object, it will be converted to string internally by jQuery using query-string format. More on that in the [jQuery documentation for $.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) (the most importatnt options being `data` and `processData`).

Comment: Hi..thx for this one...by this way i got data on php ...like this "{"ClientData":["4","kamlesh","KAM","Junagadh","me","SANTA ROSA","76220","kamlesh.vadiyatar@gmail.com","9998305904",false]}" now, how can i get one by one element?

Comment: Hi..thx for this one...by this way i got data on php ...like this "{"ClientData":["4","kamlesh","KAM","Junagadh","me","SANTA ROSA","76220","kamlesh.vadiyatar@gmail.com","9998305904",false]}" now, how can i get one by one element?

Comment: I think you already did that in your PHP code using json_decode()

Comment: print_r(json_decode('{"ClientData":["4","kamlesh","KAM","Junagadh","me","SANTA ROSA","76220","kamlesh.vadiyatar@gmail.com","9998305904",false]}')); -- works fine!

Comment: i tried $ClientData = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));

Comment: how to i get object type args ?

Comment: i will accept your ans if you can tell me : How to get object type aregument that i have post in method

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "object type args". Anyway, if you do `$ClientData = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));` then:

    `echo $ClientData->ClientData[0];  // outputs 4`
    `echo $ClientData->ClientData[1];  // outputs kamlesh`

Answer (score 3):

Just pass the ajax data param as an object, don't convert it into JSON. Then in PHP use $_POST directly.

Use firebug or chrome dev tools to analyze the ajax request and see which data is sent

Comment: i have to pass argument or it's fine?

Comment: data: ko.toJS(params) then on PHP do a var_dump to $_POST to see which data are you getting

Comment: can you please help me one more thing...i have array of data.so, how can i get element value one by one?

Comment: You could do a foreach directly to $_POST or change data todo be data: {ko: ko.toJS(params)} and then use $_POST['ko']

Comment: i done this way and getting error: "Undefined index: ko" as well i made for ClientData...and i was getting same error..can you please let me know about foreach loop.

Answer (score -1):

Use this simple jquery function to accomplish your task

```
$.ajax({           
            type: "POST",  
            url:"scripts/dummy.php",  
            data:"tbl="+table,
            dataType:"json", //if you want to get back response in json

            beforeSend: function()
            {                   

            },
            success: function(resp)
            {               

            }, 

            complete: function()
            {

            },

            error: function(e)
            {  
            alert('Error: ' + e);  
            }  

    }); //end Ajax
```

Answer (score -1):

in PHP use:

```
if(isset($_POST['ClientData'])){
   $client_data = $_POST['ClientData']
}
```

now `$client_data` variable should contain the `array`.

For debugging purpose you can use php's built-in `print_r()` function. It's pretty handy.

here's is an example:

```
//make sure it's post request
if(isset($_POST)){
   //now print the array nicely
   echo "<pre>";
   print_r($_POST);
   echo "</pre>";
}
```