# Check if alert box was shown in PHP using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, alert

I am sending data to a PHP file using AJAX and depending on what data is sent, an `alert()` is either shown or not shown.

Inside the `success` function in AJAX, how do I detect if an alert box was shown?

```
var called = $("#called").val();

$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "send.php",
   data: "name=" + called,,
   success: function(data) {
      if(alert box was shown) {
         // something happens
      }else{
         // alert box wasn't shown, something else happens.  
      }  
   }               
});
```

`send.php`:

```
<?php
if($_POST['name'] == 'john') {
   echo'
   <script>
   alert("Correct name");
   </script>
   ';
}
```

Comment: A better way would be to send a result back from the PHP using the `success` function `callback `and show the alert there

Comment: There is a problem in your code. You are sending `POST` request and receiving in `GET` request in `PHP`.

Comment: @SahilGulati Thanks, fixed that typo in my question.

Comment: @TheCodesee One more thing is You can not receive POST request data in this way. You should use `$post = file_get_contents('php://input');` Refer to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16433794/get-ajax-post-data-on-php-via-javascript-call

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be better to send back a result form the ajax request and show/don't show the alert in the `success` callback:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "send.php",
   data: "name=" + called,,
   success: function(data) {    
      if ( data == "show" ) {
         // something happens
         alert("Correct name");
      } else {
         // alert box wasn't shown, something else happens.  
      }  
   }               
});
```

And on your server:

```
if ( $_POST['name'] == 'john' ) {
   echo "show";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `json_encode()` php function to return data from php.

This will be a better approach :

PHP :

```
if (!isset($_POST['name'] || empty($_POST['name']) {
    die(json_encode(array('return' => false, 'error' => "Name was not set or is empty")));
} elseif ($_POST['name'] == "John") {
    die(json_encode(array('return' => true)));
} else {
    die(json_encode(array('return' => false, 'error' => "Name is different than John.")));
}
```

At this point, you will be allowed to check the returned values from JS and decide if you need to display the success alert or send an error message to the console (or do what ever you want...).

JS :

```
var called = $("#called").val();

$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "send.php",
   dataType: "JSON", // set the type of returned data to json
   data: {name: called}, // use more readable syntaxe
   success: function(data) {
      if (data.return) { // access the json data object 
         alert("Congrats ! Your name is John !");
      } else {
         console.log("Sorry, something went wrong : " + data.error);  
      }  
   }               
});
```

So, `json_encode()` allows to return easy accessible object from JS and will also allows you to set and display error messages easily in case the return is false.

Hope it helps !

Answer (score 0):

PHP does not know if an alert has been shown, because in javascript the alert() function has no return value and no events which you could use to send an ajax request a click confirmation to the server.

One solution is to use a confirm() command inside the success event of your $.ajax(), which sends anothe ajax request if the user clicked "ok" or "cancel".

Something like this

```
var called = $("#called").val();

$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "send.php",
   data: "name=" + called,
   success: function(data) {

        if (data == "show") {

            var clicked = confirm("Correct name");

            if (clicked == true || clicked == false) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "send.php?clicked=1",
                });
            }  
        }
        else {
             // Whatever to do than...
        } 
    }
});
```